# Passing BSON directly to MongoDB using the mong-ruby-driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

Is there a way to pass a BSON object directly into the `.find()` in the mongo-ruby-driver?

At the moment I have a basic sinatra app that takes URL encoded JSON and parses it into the .find() but I would ideally like to give it straight BSON:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'json'

include Mongo
db = MongoClient.new().db('test')

get '/' do
  if request[:query]
    query = JSON.parse(CGI::unescape(request[:query]))
    db.collection('test_collection').find(query).to_a.to_json
  end
end
```

So essentially have something along the lines of `BSON.parse(url-encoded-query)` and be able to pass that into a `.find()` returning the result.

Example URL: `http://localhost:4567/?query=%7B%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22john%20doe%22%20%7D`
Current query: `{ "name" : "john doe" }`
BSON query: `{ name: /.*john.*/, interests: [ 'fishing', 'golf' ]}` that I'd like to work

Comment: Any specific reason not to use the `params` hash? That skips the JSON generation code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - even if I pass BSON through `params` (or `request`) I still can't pass it directly to the mongo-ruby `.find()`

Comment: "Straight BSON" may not be what you think; your example "BSON" query is still JSON.  Have you read the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) .. there are some examples there of the binary format.  You should also require the [`bson_ext`](http://rubygems.org/gems/bson_ext) gem in your app as it provides better performance for serialization.

Comment: It isn't JSON - I mean I can't parse it using `JSON.parse()` and JSONLint throws up quite a few errors? Either way, I can't give it to the mongo-ruby `.find()` - it's expecting a ruby hash from what I understand.

Comment: True .. your example query isn't quite valid JSON, but if you doublequoted the strings it would be :). It's definitely not in the binary format required for BSON. In any case, you could peek into the Ruby driver source to see how it calls the underlying BSON serialisation and uses the [Mongo Wire Protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol) to talk to the server. I don't think there is really a step you can skip to gain any significant performance, because you still need to decode the URL params into a valid data structure before passing to `find()`.

Comment: Thanks! Just been digging around and I might write my own simple driver - It's not really performance I'm after - just ease; and another niggle came up that I've posted in [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/615kXh1PUss) - basically the ruby driver = .find(<query>, <opts>) whereas mongo = .find(<query>, <projection>) - I can't use projections (i.e. $elemMatch) in the ruby-driver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following test script demonstrates how to use the $elemMatch operator as a projection.  Please note that the Collection#find method takes arbitrary documents for both the "selector" formal parameter and for the "opts" :fields option.

MongoDB documents are mapped to/from Ruby Hash objects, and these documents can fully incorporate MongoDB operators.

elemmatch_projection.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Ruby translation of example from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/
require 'mongo'
coll = Mongo::MongoClient.new['test']['students']
coll.remove
coll.insert({
  zipcode: 63109,
  dependents: [
    { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
    { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
    { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
  ]
})
p coll.find( { zipcode: 63109 }, :fields => { dependents: { '$elemMatch' => { school: 102 } } } ).to_a
```

ruby elemmatch_projection.rb

```
[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('50eab29929daeb05ae000001'), "dependents"=>[{"name"=>"john", "school"=>102, "age"=>10}]}]
```

This is another answer because the question has been significantly clarified by the OP.

Hope that this helps you understand how to use MongoDB documents and operators in Ruby.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was after. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has more to do with parsing JSON or Ruby (Regexp) than with BSON.  Your original question causes confusion by jumping directly to BSON.  With the current Ruby driver, BSON is not directly exposed to the application writer, but mapped as naturally as possible from and to Ruby objects.

JSON is strictly limited and safe for parsing.  Adding parsing for Regexp moves beyond this.

You can do what you want unsafely using Kernel#eval.  This will parse your Regexp, but it will also parse exec, system, backticks, etc.  For a public application with arbitrary user input, you will have to do something safer.

Also note, the differences between the following lines, which highlights semantics with both Ruby and MongoDB:

```
{ interests: [ 'fishing', 'golf' ] }
```

The above exactly matches interests iff they are exactly [ 'fishing', 'golf' ]. no more, no less, no other order.

```
{ interests: { '$in' => [ 'fishing', 'golf' ] } }
```

The above matches interests if interests have either 'fishing' or 'golf', any order, any position, any extras.  Note that the string key '$in' requires the original => syntax.

Hope that this helps your understanding, and please feel free to followup with clarifying questions.

The following is a working example.

myapp.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'json'

include Mongo
db = MongoClient.new().db('test')

get '/' do
  if request[:query]
    query = eval CGI::unescape(request[:query])
    docs = db.collection('test_collection').find(query).to_a.to_json
    "docs=#{docs}"
  end
end
```

myapp_test.rb

```
require 'myapp'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rack/test'
require 'open-uri'
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

class MyAppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def setup
    @db ||= Mongo::MongoClient.new['test']
    @coll ||= @db['test_collection']
    @coll.remove
    @coll.insert({name: 'john doe', interests: [ 'fishing', 'golf' ]})
  end

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  def query_test(query)
    uri = "http://localhost:4567/?query=#{URI::encode(query)}"
    puts "uri=#{uri}"
    get uri
    puts last_response.body
    assert_match(/^docs=/, last_response.body)
  end

  def test_john_doe
    query_test("{ name: 'john doe'}")
  end

  def test_regexp
    query_test("{ name: /.*john.*/, interests: [ 'fishing', 'golf' ]}")
  end
end
```

ruby -I. myapp_test.rb

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

uri=http://localhost:4567/?query=%7B%20name:%20/.*john.*/,%20interests:%20[%20'fishing',%20'golf'%20]%7D
docs=[{"_id":{"$oid": "50e9e60029daeb0be1000001"},"name":"john doe","interests":["fishing","golf"]}]
.uri=http://localhost:4567/?query=%7B%20name:%20'john%20doe'%7D
docs=[{"_id":{"$oid": "50e9e60129daeb0be1000002"},"name":"john doe","interests":["fishing","golf"]}]
.

Finished tests in 0.065822s, 30.3850 tests/s, 60.7700 assertions/s.

2 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - `eval()` was the first thing I thought of, but for many reasons you mentioned already it can't be used. Digging around I found the `=> { "$regex" => { "*" } }` in Mongo (and it's the same for most query matchers) so thats no longer an issue for me. Mongo fields / projections in a query now allows `$elemMatch` which the driver doesn't yet support (you can pass many options and a fields array), so that again is another reason I want to be able to pass direct BSON.

Comment: Sure you can use $regex, but your original question and query seemed to desire parsing the Regexp.  Your use of terms is still confusing, you aren't really talking about BSON, but about the MongoDB operators http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/ -- $elemMatch is an operator and does not require additional driver support with the current driver interface.

Comment: It's also been added as a projection: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: Type the JS function in the mongo shell to show usage, e.g., db.students.find displays function (query, fields, limit, skip, batchSize, options) ...  In the Ruby documentation for find http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method usage is find(selector = {}, opts = {}) and under opts :fields is listed first! So you can verify for yourself that $elemMatch can be supplied to the MongoDB server either in selector arg or in the opts :fields opt for projection.  There's no need for specialized driver code to support $elemMatch (with the current driver).